# How to Get Objects unstuck from one another?

Tags: modeling

when I move the headlights the grill moves (btw grill is not supposed to move) but if I then try to move the headlights again the grill doesn't move. It also does it with the not very noticeable 2nd grill.
pic 1 is 1st move of the headlights
pic two is 2nd move of the headlights

[image]

[image]

Comment: You've enabled the Proportional Editing option (blue sphere button on the top of your view), is it your problem?

Comment: thank you keep forgetting that is a feature

Answer (score 1):

Disable the *Proportional Editing* option (blue sphere button on the top of your view):

[image]